# C# exception wrong encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, exception

I started working with .net core and I need to open database connection via npgsql. Here is the code:

```
try
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    await Utils.ThrowErrorAsync(session, e.Message);
    return;
}
```

The problem is that `e.Message` is in wrong codepage (without diacritics).

There is:

`28P01: autoryzacja has�em nie powiod�a si� dla u�ytkownika postgres`

but should be (polish):

`28P01: autoryzacja hasłem nie powiodła się dla użytkownika postgres`

I cannot change codepage for this exception so there is no way to stringify this error message into JSON and parse back. There is an exception thrown: `Unexpected end of JSON input`.

So my question is:

1) Is there possible to change CodePage of Exception?

2) Is there a way to remove problematic chars from this string?

Regards

Comment: @Joey I know I can simply replace that characters, the problem is I cannot recognize characters to replace. Of course I can use Regex [a-zA-Z0-9] but message will be very unclear in that case.

Comment: Where/how do you inspect that string when you see the odd characters? I ask because the string itself may be completely fine, but the transport to you, like say through a http request, or a log file, or something like this may mess this up.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: I'd strongly guess that the exception message has been taken (and parsed) from the connection to Postgres itself and thus it's the connector that mangles it because the encoding isn't the same that the database server uses.

Comment: If the string is like that in the exception, then yes, it's the building of the exception and where/how that code gets the string that is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can try replacing the offending characters. � is U+FFFD Replacement Character, so the following should suffice:

```
var cleanedMessage = e.Message.Replace('�', '?');
```

If your JSON conversion has problems with anything non-ASCII (should not happen, but such problems abound), you could also replace everything beyond ASCII:

```
var cleanedMessage = Regex.Replace(e.Message, "[^\x00-~]", "?");
```

However, fundamentally, if you see those characters, then Npgsql already did something very wrong and the problem should ideally be fixed there.

From looking at the source of that library, it uses `connector.Settings.Encoding` as the encoding to convert whatever is read from the socket. It defaults to UTF-8, but apparently it's not UTF-8 in your case, otherwise you wouldn't get those replacement characters. Codepage 1250 would be my guess in your case, but perhaps you can just use `Encoding.Default` to get that.